# How does a bot create a category with channels in it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

```
      if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Missing Parameter: `guild`")
      if(args[0] === "guild") {
      const loggingChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "katsu-member-logs");
      const katsuCategory = "Chika Logs";
      if(!loggingChannel) {
      const channelName = "katsu-member-logs";
          message.guild.channels.create(channelName, { parent: katsuCategory.id, topic: "Katsu Member Logs" }).then(c => {
              const allUsers = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "@everyone")
              c.updateOverwrite(allUsers, {
                  SEND_MESSAGES: false
              })
          });
        } else {
            await message.channel.send("Oops, it looks like `katsu-member-logs` channel already exist in this server");
        }
      }
    }
```

I have this piece of code. It is working fine as it creates the channel, however, it's not creating the text category where the channel should go. I am not quite sure on how to fix this issue. Discord.JS `v12.2.0`

Comment: It looks like you're setting `katsuCategory` to a string with the value "Chika Logs", as this is a simple string, and not a reference to the channel object for that category, it has no `id` value and can't be set as a parent of the channel. What you need to to do is create the category separately (or grab the object for the category if it's already made) and then use that to set the parent for the new channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to replace this statement with the following :

```js
const katsuCategory = "Chika Logs";
```

Should be :

```js
const katsuCategory = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'Chika Logs' && c.type === 'category');
```

You should now be able to access it's ID and create a channel using this one as a parent :)